# refactorized solve for an algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have attended a technical interview for a development company. They asked me the following:

> Giving an array of numbers (n) find 2 numbers that sum gives (k) and print them.
>     e.g

```
Input: n = [2,6,4,5,7,1], k = 8   
Output: result=(2,6),(7,1)
```

My solution:

```
function findSum(n,k){
    let aux = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i+1; j < n.length; j++) {
            if (n[i] + n[j] == k) {
                aux.push({ first: n[i], second: n[j] })
            }
        }
    }
    return aux;
}
```

They told me that, it is possible to make the exercise with some kind of key or mapping.
Does some one know how to do it with only one loop?

Comment: You are checking all pairs O(n^2), you could use a hashtable, inserting all elements would be O(n), traversing again would be O(n) with constant compares.  O(n + n) = O(n)

Comment: Inserting an element cost O(log n), thus inserting all elements costs O(n * log n), and overall complexity is O(n * log n)

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky Where do you get O(log n) from? Inserting elements with a good hashfunction in to a table does not cost O(log n).

Answer (score 5):

The key to solving a question like this with low time complexity is the ability to efficiently search the data structure. A lot of answers rearrange the array in a way where searching an array is optimized. Another approach is with a data structure that inherently has fast search.

Set and Map data structures have O(1) time complexity for searches, which make them good data structures where searching can be leveraged to increase performance.

I use a `new Map` and traverse the array while adding it as a key. I set the `key` to the number and the value to the number of times I see it. I use a map over a `new Set` because I can also keep track of the number of instances of that particular number.

I search for the number that would sum up to `k`, which is: (`k` - `num`). If I find that number, I add both numbers to my results data structure and decrement the `value` by 1, to show that it's been used.

Time complexity: O(n), memory complexity: O(2n). Twice the amount of space compared to the original array because I have a `key` and a `value` to store in my `Map`

```js
function pairSums(arr, k){
    const map = new Map
    const matches = []
    for (let num of arr) {
        const search = k - num 
        if (map.get(search) > 0) {
            matches.push([num, k - num])
            map.set(search, map.get(search) - 1)
        } else if (!map.has(num)){
            map.set(num, 1)
        } else {
            map.set(num, map.get(num) + 1)
        }
    }
    return matches
}

console.log(pairSums([2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2], 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

Match a number `x` from array with a key `Math.min(x, k - x)`. Then run through your array and store every number in a hash using mentioned key. When the key you are going to add already is in the hash - check if stored value and current number gives required sum.

```
function findSum(n, k){
  let hash = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < n.length; ++i){
    let x = n[i], key = Math.min(x, k - x);
    if((key in hash) && hash[key] + x == k)
      return [hash[key], x];
    else hash[key] = x;
  }
}
```

Comment: The if statement doesnt do other loop?(key in hash)

Comment: Based on the expected output, it looks like OP is looking for every instance of a correct summation. Not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A task like this can be as simple or as complicated as you want to make it. Here's one solution, for example:

```
function findPairs(n, k) {
    return n.reduce((pairs, next, i) => pairs.concat(
        n.slice(i + 1)
            .filter(num => next + num === k)
            .map(num => [ next, num ])
        ),
        []
    );
}
```

For the inputs `[2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 1]` and `8` will output `[ [2, 6], [7, 1] ]`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that last part. Go figure.

Comment: Considering the number of loops is misleading, because these function calls may embed "hidden" loops. What matters is the complexity function.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what @DaveNewton was pointing out as well. All function calls in my solution probably execute a loop, so the time complexity is much greater.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/:

1. Sort the array in non-decreasing order.
2. Initialize two index variables to find the candidate elements in the sorted array. Initialize `l` to the leftmost index: `l = 0`, Initialize `r` to the rightmost index: `r = n.length - 1`
3. Loop while `l` < `r`.

   1. `if (n[l] + n[r] == k)` then `return 1`
   2. `else if( n[l] + n[r] <  k )`  then `l++`
   3. `else r--`
4. No candidates in whole array - `return 0`

Comment: Wouldn't the sorting be considered (at least) a loop? (And potentially longer?)

Comment: I suppose it’s up to the interviewer to count that or not, but yes it would. You could do it in O(n log n) with this solution, but better solutions have since been posted above

Answer (score 0):

I think by sorting you can do that

```
var n = [2,6,4,5,7,1];
var k = 8 ;
n.sort();


let start = 0, end = n.length-1;
while(start < n.length && end >= 0) {
    let current_sum = (n[start] + n[end]);
    if(current_sum == k) {
        console.log('Found sum with '+ n[start] +' and '+ n[end]);
        break;
    }
    else if(current_sum > k) {
        end--;
    } else {
        start++;
    }
}
if(start == n.length || end < 0) {
    console.log('Not Found');
}
```

but while writing this code I got one another approach also

```
const set = new Set([2,6,4,5,7,1]);
var k = 8;
let found = false;
for (let item of set) {
    let another = k - item;
    if(set.has(another)){ 
        console.log('found with '+item +' and ' +another);
        found = true;   
        break;
    }
}
if(!found) {
    console.log('Not found');
}
```

Comment: Using a set stops working in certain situations if there are duplicate numbers in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If numbers are non-negative and the target value is within JavaScript array limit:

```js
function findsums(arr,k){
    var ret=[];
    var aux=[];
    arr.forEach(function(i){
      if(i<=k){
        if(aux[k-i])
          ret.push([k-i,i]);
        aux[i]=true;
      }
    });
    return ret;
}

console.log(findsums([2,6,4,5,7,1],8));
```

Similar approach could work with a bitfield (or even with a sparse array of bitfields) too.

Answer (score 0):

Minified alternative similar to @Andrew's great answer, but assumes that all numbers are above 0 :

```js
var pairs = (arr, k) => arr.reduce((a, n) => 
  (a[n - k]-- ? a.push([n, k - n]) : a[-n] = a[-n] | 0 + 1, a), []);

console.log(JSON.stringify( pairs([2,6,4,5,7,1], 8) ));
```